# MATLAB PDF Output Incorrect When Axes Removed

Tags: matlab, pdf, postscript

I'm trying to generate a PDF file from a figure to scale in MATLAB. I'm trying to hide the axes in the figure because I'm basically just drawing a bunch of rectangles (a chessboard). Whenever I try to hide the axes (either `set(gca,'Visible','off');` or `axis off;`), the PDF output seems clipped (only one rectangle from my chessboard shows). Any idea why turning the axes off is screwing everything up?

Here's the code -- I'm just trying to generate a chessboard to scale

```
% Create a figure to get paper sizes
clear all;
clf;

% Use centimetres
set(gcf,'PaperUnits','centimeters');

% Get the paper dimensions
dims = get(gcf,'PaperSize');

inner_corner_x = 8;
inner_corner_y = 11;
margin = 2.5; % cm
dims = dims - 2*margin;

sz = round(min((dims(1)) / (inner_corner_x + 2), (dims(2)) / (inner_corner_y + 2)));

for i = 0:inner_corner_y
    for j = 0:inner_corner_x
        if mod(i + j, 2) == 0
            color = 'k';
        else
            color = 'w';
        end
        rectangle(...
            'Position', [j * sz i * sz sz sz],...
            'FaceColor', color,...
            'EdgeColor', color);
    end
end

% PROBLEM IS HERE
% Comment this line out to have ugly output, but at least all chessboard blocks show...
axis off;

set(gca,'LooseInset', get(gca,'TightInset'));
set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','manual');
set(gcf,'PaperPosition',[margin margin dims]);

print -dpdf figure1
```

Comment: Matlab's figure exporting is an absolute mess.  I hate it.  This isn't a direct answer, but I generally have the best luck exporting to EPS/EPSC first and then using Illustrator to clean up the image bounds and convert to a PDF.  But this only works if you have a secondary program that can read encapsulated postscript files.

Comment: Try to use [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig).

Comment: `export_fig` appears to ignore all of my paper size settings. It doesn't looks like it really supports exporting with a given scale, or at least I can't find controls for it...

Comment: It will be a pain if you have lots of figures, but use 'file/save as' from the figure window. I get good results with your code doing that.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing a PostScript file by hand to generate the chessboard. This particular script generates a PDF on a 8.5" x 11" paper size with 7x9 boxes in it. You set the box size in points (72 in this case is 1"). Sorry this answer is kind of irrelevant to the question, but I really couldn't get the nice output I wanted for such a simple figure so I did it manually and it worked nicely.

```
%!PS
/ptsx 8.5 72 mul def
/ptsy 11  72 mul def
/boxx 7 def
/boxy 9 def
/sz 72 def

boxx sz mul ptsx gt {(Size too wide for page!) print quit} if
boxy sz mul ptsy gt {(Size too tall for page!) print quit} if

/marginx ptsx boxx sz mul sub 2 div def
/marginy ptsy boxy sz mul sub 2 div def

0 0 0 setrgbcolor
marginx marginy translate

/xval 0 def
/yval 0 def
/xon true def
/yon true def
0 1 boxy 1 sub {
  0 1 boxx 1 sub {
    newpath
    xval yval moveto
    xval yval sz add lineto
    xval sz add yval sz add lineto
    xval sz add yval lineto
    xon {fill} if
    /xval xval sz add def
    /xon xon not def
  } for
  /xval 0 def
  /yval yval sz add def
  /yon yon not def
  /xon yon def
} for
```